# Drawing a JLabel with X,Y coordinate of the center

Tags: java, swing, coordinates, jlabel

I am trying to draw a JLabel (or JComponent with an image) in such a way that its location is the center of the image, not the top-left corner.

I've tried to use `fillOval` and `drawImage` to no avail. I have a model of the object which has a position of 16x16, and I wish the sprite to span from 0x0 to 32x32, not 16x16 to 48x48.

Resumed in an image : getLocation() should give me the model's position (i.e. the center) and when I try to paint, it should paint with the x,y coordinates in the center, not on the top left corner.

Any idea?

[image]

Some bits of my code : The JPanel trying to display the sprites on update :

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) { //Is ran everytime WorldControler simulates a tick
    this.removeAll();
    paintCreatures(arg);
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param arg : The LinkedList that notifyObserver passes through in WorldControler
 */
private void paintCreatures(Object arg){
    LinkedList<Creature> cList = (LinkedList<Creature>) arg;
    for(Creature c : cList){
        ViewCreature vc = new ViewCreature(c,8);
        this.add(vc);
        vc.setVisible(true);
        vc.setSize(8,8);
        System.out.println(vc.getX() + " " + vc.getY());
    }
}
```

The paintComponent I currently have :

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(img, this.getX()+size/2, this.getY()+size/2, null);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to position the lable rather than the picture within the lable. This could be done using a FlowLayout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

Comment: As I am working with absolute positions (this is an evolution simulator, so creatures are expected to move around pixel by pixel), I am currently using `setLayout(null)`. From what I've read, it's the only way to give a precise position on the JPanel. Is there another way?

Comment: so you may have a look here: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/893471/Fun-with-Java-Sprite-Animation-Part-1.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually solved the problem is by offsetting the Location in the setLocation method. It's not the most beautiful of answers, but for now it'll do the job.

```
@Override
public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    super.setLocation(x-(size/2), y-(size/2));
}
@Override
public void setLocation(Point p) {
    super.setLocation((int)p.getX()-size/2,(int)p.getY()-size/2);
}
```

If you have any suggestion to improve this answer, please comment or answer yourself.
There is no need to override paintComponent with this.